# Ubuntu 20.04 not booting after fresh install

Tags: boot, 20.04, boot-repair

So after installing ubuntu on my old laptop and giving it to my grandpa, it eventually died, but he liked using ubuntu. So he bought a new one and asked me to install it. So I did, but it won't boot. So I booted back into the install USB, and after following something online that said to use boot-repair, I did. It ended up giving an error in the report, which is shown in the imgur link I'm putting at the end of this. I also show the contents of device.map, as well as what disks shows. I can't for the life of me fix this. Please help.
[http://imgur.com/gallery/hJYdDmT](https://imgur.com/gallery/hJYdDmT)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check latest available kernel: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/linux-image-generic. Your kernel looks out of date
2. Boot and select oldest available kernel
3. replace `@@kernal@@` with `a.b.c-d-generic` where `a.b.c-d` is version you see in step 1

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k @@kernal@@
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: if my kernel is out of date, why would i boot with the oldest available? wouldn't it need the newest? and if that's the case, why did i not have this problem with my desktop, which i installed ubuntu on from the same USB i used for this laptop? i can't try this right now, so i'm gonna try and make sure everything is right before i get a chance to do it tomorrow.

Comment: I do unattended installs,  however I have observed multiple times that kernel that comes from ISO works and install process partially installs updated kernel that then prevents boot.   Booting with kernel in ISO works so that you can then fully install most unto date kernel

Comment: huh. odd. so i do want to boot using the oldest kernel? and how do i boot using the oldest kernel in the first place, if i can't even get to GRUB?i can boot from the install USB, but that's it. sorry for a lot of questions, i don't know a ton about the basic systems of linux, since every time i've installed it thus far, i haven't had any issues, so i'm not sure of what to do when there ARE issues. thanks in advance.